# WPF: Как привязаться к DependencyProperty в xaml или добавить кастомное свойсто для контрола?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Есть контро, который нужно использовать в двух вариантах:

- горизонтальное расположение элементов
- вертикальное расположение элементов

Для этого я создал сам контрол BytePropertyView.xaml:

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource MainBorder}">
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                   Style="{StaticResource MainName}"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
!!!Сюда нужно подписаться!!!
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </WrapPanel>
</Border>
```

А вот его .cs код(это не VM, а код, который генерирует сама IDE и в него я добавил DP) BytePropertyView.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class BytePropertyView : UserControl
{
    public BytePropertyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Orientation ItemsOrientation
    {
        get { return (Orientation)GetValue(ItemsOrientationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsOrientationProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsOrientationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsOrientation", typeof(Orientation), typeof(BytePropertyView), new PropertyMetadata(Orientation.Horizontal));
}
```

Мне нужно подписать Orientation в ItemsControl на свойство ItemsOrientation.
Или как лучше добавить кастомное свойство для контрола?

Comment: Ага, теперь понятно, пока без ПК, поэтому напишу в комменариях: задайте вашему UsrControl имя в разметке и привяжитесь: `{Binding ItemsOrientation, ElementName=name}`

Comment: Можно ещё через RelativeSource FindAncestor, но это будет более громоздко

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо вам большое! Надеюсь когда-нибудь смогу достичь вашего уровня знании!

Comment: Если все получилось – напишите ответ

Comment: @АндрейNOP готово! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для привязки необходимо присвоить имя `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GraceConfig.View.BytePropertyView"
             ...
             Name="ByteProperty">
```

А там, где необходимо подписаться указать название свойства и имя `UserControl`:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="{Binding ItemsOrientation,
                        ElementName=ByteProperty}"/>
```

При использовании устанавливаем свойство:

```
<local:BytePropertyView ItemsOrientation="Vertical"/>
```